# Xaringan slides advance with odd latency in presentation

Tags: r, transition, presentation, xaringan

I am presenting my slides (same problem in in RStudio as in browser) and the transitions have weird latency. New text comes in, but old text doesn't go away for more than 0.5 sec.

I have a [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Q99rV1SRfrI) that illustrates the problem.

Not really sure where the problem stems from. Any suggestions?

Comment: Lars, is it reproducible on another computer?  If so (or if you don't know) could you post the .Rmd file?

Comment: Yes, it reproduces on rstudio.cloud, for example. I put it in an open project [here](https://rstudio.cloud/project/1598655). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises from a mismatch between R's color names and HTML/CSS color names. Here is the source code chunk used in the slides to create the [xaringanthemer](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanthemer) CSS:

````
```{r xaringan-themer, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(xaringanthemer)
style_xaringan(title_slide_background_image = "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2567196.jpg",
               background_color = "grey14",
               title_slide_text_color = "white"
               )
```
````

Unfortunately `"grey14"` is an R color, but it's not recognized by HTML, so the slide background becomes transparent. A warning is emitted that hexadecimal colors are expected if used by `theme_xaringan()`, so I understand why the warning was ignored.

In some cases, the color names are the same — e.g. `"white"` is both an R and HTML color — so it made sense to me to warn rather than throw an error in cases like these.

You can use `col2rgb()` to lookup the rgb or hex representation of the color:

```r
col2rgb("grey14")
#>       [,1]
#> red     36
#> green   36
#> blue    36
rgb(36, 36, 36, maxColorValue = 255)
#> [1] "#242424"
```

So either `background_color="#242424"` or `background_color = "rgb(36,36,36)"` would create slides with a solid background.

Comment: Fantastic! Yes, this explanation makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I was able to chase down the problem.  It is that when you change slides that class temporarily changes from `remark-visible` to `remark-fading` which keeps the existing slide active for 1 second.  I'm not sure why this particular thing happened (I don't recall it happening when I've made xaringan slides in the past).  In any event, you can stop it by putting the following block in your first slide after the background image.  Then, everything seemed to work fine for me.

```
htmltools::tags$style("
.remark-fading{
  display:none
}
")
```

I also changed it in the RStudio.cloud project and it worked there.  I added it right after the `background-image()` line of the first slide.